# Displaying text without interrupts

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I am trying to make my own boot-loader. As I will not have any interrupts when I change from 16bit to 32 bit mode, I will not be able to use `int 10h`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
org 0x7c00            ; add to offsets
xor ax, ax            ; make it zero
mov ds, ax            ; ds=0
mov ss, ax            ; stack starts at 0

cld

mov ax, 0xb800        ; Ax = address of video memory
mov es, ax
xor di, di
call print            ; call thr print function

hang:
   jmp hang           ; constanly loop

print:
  mov si, msg         ; load msg into si
  mov cx, 4
  mov ah, 07h

printchar:
  lodsb               ; Hear we load a letter from si
  stosw
  loop printchar      ; if not end of msg, go back to printchar
  ret                 ; return

msg    db    'test'   ; msg = 'test'

times 510-($-$$) db 0 ; make sure file is 510 bytes in size
dw 0xaa55             ; write boot signiture
```

And compiled with nasm:

```
nasm -f bin bootloader.asm -o myos.hdd
```

I have put comments in the lines I understand. What I don't understand is the usage of the video memory. Could someone explain this to me and show me where to find the documentation?

I have searched the internet but cannot find the documentation.

Comment: have you found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode ? (it's not like asm tutorial, but the technical information there is actually sufficient to break it on your own ... and of course there must be ton of examples in old sources around, but I'm too lazy to search)

Comment: you should put `hlt` inside your infinite loop, or `cli` / `hlt`, to save power (or emulator CPU time) vs `jmp $`.

Comment: @Ped7g That is some useful information, unfortunately as you say it doesn't talk about it in terms of assembly. This means I don't know what I should put in each register as an argument. That link is still good though.

Comment: You can start from [here](https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_UI). BTW that part between reading the specs and "what to put in each register" (AKA coding) is where *all* the fun is.

Comment: you don't need to put into register anything. You need to modify memory area starting at `B800:0000`, that's where VGA card does 60 times per second (with 60Hz display mode) look for value of every text-grid-rectangle, loads the character value and attribute value, and builds pixel info according to those (and the font data stored in VGA card elsewhere). And you may change the VGA control registers values (by doing many `out` ins.) to change particular display mode/features... but if you already did set the mode with `int 10h` in real mode (I recommend it for toy OS), then just write into VRAM

Comment: of course to modify memory, you usually will load some values into some registers, and then write those back into the memory at desired address, but that's quite free to you, how you will employ registers and which instructions you will use, there are many ways how to modify values in memory, some of them more fit for particular task than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I get it now.

`mov cx, 4` is the length of the message. "test" is four bytes long.

`mov ah, 07h` is setting the colour data. 0 = black, 7 = light grey.
First number is the background colour, second number is the text colour.
This means that the character to be printed will be light grey on a black background.

Thank you to everyone who helped.

Comment: yes. And the `stosw` writes 16 bit value from `ax`, so both letter+attribute is written at every time, and `lodsb` will refresh only the letter part (low 8 bits = `al`) of `ax`, the upper 8 bits `ah` stay `0x07` for whole print subroutine, i.e. for every letter.