# How to understand what to put in registers from documentation?

Tags: assembly, specifications, cpu-registers

I was trying to understand how to display text in VGA mode the other day so I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52643208/displaying-text-without-interrupts/52647221?noredirect=1#comment92227193_52647221). I now understand how it works but through trial an error.

What got me interested was what @Margaret Bloom mentioned in one of the comments:

> BTW that part between reading the specs and "what to put in each register" (AKA coding) is where all the fun is.

To me, this suggests that it is possible to know which registers to use and what to put in them just by reading the specifications.

Using the VGA Text Mode example, What would suggest that you put the address `0xB8000` into `ax` and `dx`, position of the character in `di` and the character and colour code in `ES:DI`?

Also when reading C code such as the below,

```
void WriteCharacter(unsigned char c, unsigned char forecolour, unsigned char backcolour, int x, int y)
{
     uint16_t attrib = (backcolour << 4) | (forecolour & 0x0F);
     volatile uint16_t * where;
     where = (volatile uint16_t *)0xB8000 + (y * 80 + x) ;
     *where = c | (attrib << 8);
}
```

how would I know to put the values in their corresponding registers?

Knowing this in the future will help me as I will be able to understand what and where to put data in the future.

I hope this all makes sense. If not, feel free to ask me to clarify.

The documentation is [linked hear](https://wiki.osdev.org/Text_UI)

Answer (score 1):

Writing characters to VGA memory is about modifying *memory*.  It doesn't matter which registers you use to make that happen, only the end result of modifying the contents of memory from linear address `0xB8000` to wherever the end of VGA memory is.

When compiling that C function, a compiler has total freedom to use whatever registers it wants (as long as it preserves all call-preserved registers according to the calling convention); the only observable side effect is the store through a `volatile uint16_t*`.

The rest is all local variables with automatic storage, so the "as-if" rule allows it to produce that side-effect using whatever code it wants.

Comment: Could you explain this in more detail for me? For example, why does it 'not matter' which registers are used? How would I be able to use any registers I want to etc.?

Comment: I'm also wanting to know how this works for a generic specification too. VGA Text Memory just so happens to be my example.

Comment: @iProgram: If you put the right values in DS, BX and AX, `mov [ds:bx], ax` will do the job.  Or if you put the right values in ES, DI, and CX, then `mov [es:di], cx` will store the same 2 bytes to the same linear address.  There are a zillion ways to code anything in asm, using different registers.  If you want to use `stosw`, then your choice of registers is limited, but that instruction isn't special; it doesn't do anything that you can't do with multiple other instructions.

Comment: Can you go into more detail with some code examples please? Not sure if I understand. I am new to assembly. Also thanks for helping me a lot!

Comment: @iProgram I suggest you to do some assembly programming following a tutorial first.  Your question is the kind of confusion that clears itself up really quickly once you start to get your feet wet with some exercises.  On the other hand, further explanations by people on this site are unlikely to help as none of us can understand this for you.